# How to BIND before and after POPSTATE while working with AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-events

While working with slow AJAX showing "loading..." to the user was a good thing.
Now I have history working using `history.pushState` and `history.popState`, but it doesn't show me my loading image while performing actual ajax on backbutton pressed!

```
$(window).bind("popstate", function() {
  $.get(location.href);
  //$.getScript(location.href);
});
```

How to do something like `$(window).bind("before_popstate", function() {});`?

BTW I'm running Rails in background...

PSS

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).bind("popstate", function() {
  $.get(location.href);
  });

$('.remote')
.bind("ajax:beforeSend", function(evt, xhr, settings){
      $('#mainframe').html("");
      $('#loading').toggle();
   })
.bind("ajax:success", function(evt, data, status, xhr){
  $('#loading').toggle();
})
.bind('ajax:complete', function(evt, xhr, status){
      history.pushState(null, document.title, path)
})
.bind("ajax:error", function(evt, xhr, status, error){
      $('#mainframe').html("error");
      $('#loading').toggle();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$(window).bind("popstate", function() {
    your-showAjaxLoader-function()
    $.get(location.href);
    //$.getScript(location.href);
    your-removeAjaxLoader-function()
});
```

or something of that nature. I, myself, have the ajaxLoader-GIF called as a pre-processor for history and an ajaxLoader-GIF remover after the call or within the call.

UPDATE:
I see that you are toggling the "loading" on three of the bindings BUT NOT in COMPLETE. I, myself, avoid the use of toggle specially if I have to nest commands. ON START, you could use .show() and for all others, .hide().

Now, back to the real issue: "the loading is not showing". It looks like everything is okay code-wise. Are you sure the "< img src " is right in your code for "loading"?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn`t work for me. *) Don`t even know why *((((

Answer (score 0):

One more thing: are you sure the z-index for loading and the location for it are correct? I assume you want LOADING to overlay whatever and, hopefully, be on an opacity-ed background.